# Rails mailer not working Net::OpenTimeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, mailer

Rails Server is running in local Mac.
Mailer works and sends mail in my office network, but doesn't work in my home (broadband) network. Some network issue?

Here is the error:

```
Net::OpenTimeout
```

Here is my setting in development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'gmail',
    authentication: 'plain',
    user_name:  '***@gmail.com',
    password: '******',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  #config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  host = 'localhost:3000'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host, protocol: 'https' }
```

I have tried using different ports but no help. What could be the issue, or how can I debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it definitely seems like network issue.
As MacOS got rid of `telnet`, you could use `netcat`:

```
$ nc -vz smtp.gmail.com 587
Connection to smtp.gmail.com port 587 [tcp/submission] succeeded!
```

Then ask your internet provider support if it was not "succeeded".
Wrong port timed out example:

```
nc -vz smtp.gmail.com 1187
nc: connectx to smtp.gmail.com port 1187 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out
```